# Mac - Print to Google Cloud Print/HP eprint as a normal printer

Tags: macos, printing, google-cloud-print

I have an HP printer that is set up with hp eprint, which is set up with google cloud print.

My goal is to be able to print to the printer from anywhere in the world (I would have settled to just be able to print over wifi, but my printer refuses to work with my computer).

I had thought about setting up a computer on my network (With a static ip or whatever), and having that computer run a script, which was effectively being a internet printer protocol proxy, taking all requests sent to it and sending them to google cloud print, then sending the status back to the client.

My Question is 2 parts:
A: Is this the right way to go about this? and
B: If so, how do I create that printer proxy?

I am on mac.

If I am unclear or you need more information let me know.

Thanks,
Ari

**EDIT:** I like @MarkSetchell's answer, but I really need it to be a virtual printer-ish thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something with Dropbox quite easily. Set up a Mac folder action on a folder in your Dropbox that prints whatever arrives in that folder, then just save files in that folder when you want them printed. You can also Email to Dropbox.